# Xamarin.Forms: Tabs with Sharnado.presentation.forms do not respond to tap

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabs

I'm trying to use [Sharpnado's awesome tab](https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms) functionality to create what they call "Fixed tabs". But it is not doing what I want it to - and the problem may lay somewhere else... Basically, the tabs are not responding to a tap. I have narrowed it down to just that with this simple exampl.

The context is an app that uses an ordinary tabbed page (with navigation pages for each tab). On one of these tabs I have tried to put the `TabHostView`control - even without binding as I originally thought that was the problem. This is a screenshot of the test page:
[image: Sample page]
Nothing happens when I tap the two tabs ("Personlig" and "Udforsk"). The XAML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:tabs="clr-namespace:Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms.CustomViews.Tabs;assembly=Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms"
        xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
        ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Angler.Views.Partials"
        x:Class="Angler.Views.StatisticsPage">
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource PageTitle}" />
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="LightYellow">
        <Label Text="{Binding ShowSelectedTab}" Margin="20,10" />
        <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Margin="0"
                BackgroundColor="LightPink" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <tabs:TabHostView ShadowType="Bottom" Grid.Row="0">
                <tabs:TabHostView.Tabs>
                    <tabs:UnderlinedTabItem Label="Personlig" />
                    <tabs:UnderlinedTabItem Label="Udforsk" IsSelected="True" />
                </tabs:TabHostView.Tabs>
            </tabs:TabHostView>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The viewmodel looks like this (although the above has been narrowed down to not using the property for the tabindex. But I did also investigate if the binding context for the viewmodel was Ok - and it seems to be):

```
public class StatisticsPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public int SelectedTabIndex { get; set; }
    public string ShowSelectedTab { get { return $"Index: {SelectedTabIndex}"; } }
    public StatisticsPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IPageDialogService pageDialogService,
        IDeviceService deviceService) : base(navigationService, pageDialogService,
            deviceService)
    {
        Title = AppResources.StatisticsPageTitle;
    }

    public override void OnAppearing()
    {
        //SelectedTabIndex = 1;
        base.OnAppearing();
        Analytics.TrackEvent("Navigate to Statistics");
    }
}
```

I'm using VisualStudio for Mac 8.3.4 (build 8), Sharpnado.presentations.forms 1.3.0 and Prism.forms 7.2.0.1367.

I have tried to add `InputTransparent="True"` to some of the container objects - with no effect.

Any good ideas as to how to solve this is most appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this was just stupid (and a waste of two days!)...

In trying to solve other issues I had stepped back in my source repo - and once too far back... So the initialization of Sharpnado in the platforms projects were not there. That kind of made a difference.

So you will see this kind of behavious if you have not remembered to add this line to your platform projects:

```
SharpnadoInitializer.Initialize()
```

Just leaving it here in the case that someone else might end up with the same symptom :-)

Comment: Mmmhh I think I need to highlight this in a better way :)

Comment: Yep, @JackHua-MSFT - but one has to wait 2-3 days after posting a solution to your own answer before you can mark it as an answer :-)